# why try-catch is not required here in public void run()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, runnable

I have a simple program for splash screen. In which I have created a class that impements `Runnable` and overrides `run()` method.

```
class mysplash implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }
    }
}
```

If I write following code , Eclipse shows an error:

> Remove catch clause

I have a prior experience in Java and AFAIK we should write the content of run() method in try - catch block to avoid `interruptedexception` for thread.

I am a newbie in Android. Can anyone explain why exception handling is required for `run()` method in Java but not in Android?

Comment: This is no speciality of Android. Your code can't throw an `InterruptedException`, because there is no method that does that. So there should it come from? I guess your former experience included the use of `Thread.sleep()` or `Thread.wait()`. These methods can throw an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Can you share a "Java" snippet where catching `InterruptedException` like this would be required, so we can explain what's the difference there.

Comment: @laalto...oh...thanks if I use throw new InterruptedException than eclipse is not showing any error. So, is it the specialty of eclipse? sure?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse then **format your code**. Eclipse will format your code so it looks correct, not the illegible block you have posted. If you want to code, first and foremost learn to use your IDE. Further, adhere to Java naming conventions - classes should always be in `PascalCase` - variables should be in `camelCase`.

Comment: @Tom exactly..thanks...I am a fool student and now I remembered I have used Thread.sleep() and Thread.wait while writing try and catch blocks inside run(). Thanks you so much for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because `InterruptedException` will never be thrown from your try code block.